# Boundedness of a sequence in Orlicz Space

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, orlicz-spaces, summability-theory

By the Definition of Orlicz function $M$, we know that $M(0)=0$, $M(x)>0$ for $x>0$ and $M(x)\rightarrow \infty$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$. And the Orlicz-Luxemborg norm is given by $$\|x\|=\inf\left\{r>0:\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}M\left(\frac{x_n}{r}\right)\leq 1\right\}.$$

Using this, can we conclude that
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}M\left(\frac{x_n}{r}\right)\leq 1$ implies $x_n$ is a bounded sequence.

Comment: How is $x_n$ defined? What even is $x_n$?

Comment: $x_n$ is a sequence of non negative real numbers.

Comment: So for the definition of $\|x\|$ do you fix some $n$, or do you want $M(\frac{x_n}r)\leq1$ for all $n$?

Comment: I am confused by the definition of an Orlicz function, as the $x_n$ term comes out of nowhere and it is never mentioned when or how it is defined.

Comment: Edited... Please see now

Comment: I am still confused, maybe you can give an example? Say explain what is the Orlicz-Luxemborg norm of $M(x)=x$ and why?

Comment: When $M(x)=x^p, p\geq 1$ then the Orlicz Luxembourg norm reduces to the classical $\ell_p$ norm.

Comment: Ah I think I understand now. So when you write $M(x)$ then $x$ is a real number, but when you write $\|x\|$ then $x$ is an element of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$, right? If this is the case, please edit your question to make this more clear.

Comment: @J.Yomcha I cleaned up your formatting a little. Please check to make sure I didn't inadvertently change the meaning of what you've posted.

Comment: It seems $x$ is a sequence $(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots)$ and a norm $\|x\|$ is defined by that formula.

Answer (score 0):

If $(x_n)$ was not bounded, then there would be a subsequence $\left(x_{n_k}\right)_{k\geqslant 1}$ such that $\lvert x_{n_k}\rvert\gt k$ for all $k$. Therefore, 
$$
1\geqslant\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}M\left(\frac{\lvert x_{n}\rvert}r\right)\geqslant \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}M\left(\frac{\lvert x_{n_k}\rvert}r\right)\geqslant \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}M\left(\frac{ k }r\right)
$$
and since $M(x)\to +\infty$ as $x$ goes to $+\infty$, we get a contradiction.